# How to fix header and footer to show properly when you change browser window size?

Tags: css

If you minize your browser to smaller size, my site header and footer color 
is erased. If you minize your browswer you will realize what do I mean.
Here is the picture what happened to my site if you minimize the window of internet browser. It's not easy to explain, because it loads perfectly fine on maximized browser window. my site url is www.virmodrosti.com

[image]

Here is the code from style.css

```
#footer {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 background: #0b3e61;
 color: #CCD8E4;
 padding: 12px 0;
 font-size: 12px;
}

#footer a {
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #ABB9C7; 
 text-decoration: none;
}

#footer a:hover {
 color: #ABB9C7; 
 text-decoration: underline;
}

#header {
 background-color: #0A3952;
 padding: 4px 0 20px 0; 
}

#header .menu {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 60px;
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase; 
 line-height: 40px;
}

body {
 background: #DEDEDE;
 font-family: Frutiger, Lato, Georgia, serif;
 font-size: 13px; 
}

#wrapper { 
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%; 
}

#wrapper2 { 
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 86px;
 width: 1180px; 
}
```

Kindly let me know what do I need to change in style.css in order to show properly?

Comment: share your code for better understanding

Comment: Please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added the code to my post

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have:

```
#main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1180px;
    padding: 20px 20px;
}
```

The width is set to always be 1180px, as the window size is shrinking that is staying the same and stretching further than your header if that makes sense.

Comment: Yea, but the main shouldn't affect header, since it's below header id.

Comment: What's happening is your content's width stretches out further than your header and footer.

Comment: I've been struggling with issue for a long time and will be trully glad to know what to correct in css style

Comment: I'd recommend using percentages for the widths in your main container rather than using pixels. That way it will scale with the users browsers and be more responsive.

Comment: I added width: 1600px to style.css file at #header and it wasn't stretched to smaller size anymore when resizing browser but if I put 100% it is strected as usual.

Comment: I also found that sometimes it changes background from gray to white, but I don't have why since white i nowhere in css file. I always use light gray color, it is really strange that these things happen on my site.